# Any way to reuse entity data in a reducer on ngRx (Angular) so there are not multiple API calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

is there any way to connect a selector and a reducer in ngRx entities ? At the moment I am doing an API call each time I send the action and enters to this part of the reducer:

```
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService, private store: Store) {}

  searchFieldChanged(query: string) {
    this.moviesService
      .getMovies()
      .subscribe((movies) =>
        this.store.dispatch(retrievedMovieListFiltered({ movies, query }))
      );
  }
}
```

.

```
export const moviesReducer = createReducer<PopularMovieState>(
  initialState,
  on(retrievedMovieList, (state, { movies }) =>
    movieAdapter.addMany(movies, state)
  ),
  on(retrievedMovieListFiltered, (state, { movies, query }) =>
    movieAdapter.setAll(
      movies.filter((movie) => movie.title.includes(query)),
      { ...state }
    )
  )
```

.

I would like to find a way to filter among the movies array with the query provided without doing an API call each time the user types a character.

In other words, is there any way I could use this other selector I have written (last one):

```
export const moviesFeatureSelector =
  createFeatureSelector<PopularMovieState>('movies');

const { selectEntities, selectAll } = movieAdapter.getSelectors();

export const selectMoviesEntities = createSelector(
  moviesFeatureSelector,
  selectEntities
);

export const selectMovies = createSelector(moviesFeatureSelector, selectAll);

export const selectMovie = createSelector(
  selectMoviesEntities,
  selectRouteParams,
  (movies, { movieId }) => movies[movieId]
);

export const selectFilteredMovies = (title: string) =>
  createSelector(selectMovies, (movies) =>
    movies.filter((movie) => movie.title.includes(title))
  );
```

and apply it to the reducer ? I mean, I need to update the not sure if I am explaining correctly.

I can provide my repo link if it is usefu

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the request outside of ngrx you can just load the movies when the component initializes, and filter them on user input

```
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService, private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.moviesService
      .getMovies()
      .subscribe((movies) =>
        this.movies = movies
      );
  }

  movies: any[] = [];

  searchFieldChanged(query: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(retrievedMovieListFiltered({ this.movies, query })) 
  }
}
```